# Balancing a sprite

Tags: ios, rotation, sprite-kit, game-physics, skphysicsbody

So my problem regards the rotation of a sprite. I want it look like it's balancing. When you tap left - the sprite moves left, when you tap right - the sprite moves right. To get a better idea, put a pencil on it's end and try balance it... Yeah... that (but only in x axis).

Currently I am rotating a sprite either clockwise or anti-clockwise dependent upon whether I tap the left or right side of the screen. This is all done using SKActions.

The problem with this is that it results in a very 'jerky' and not particularly realistic motion.

I assume that I want to use physics body and something similar to velocity but my questions are:

- the use of velocity is right... isn't it?
- would i better off with a volume based sprite (and get it to take into account it's volume and mass) or just a simple edge based sprite?

Thanks in advance!

-- Code - 
This is how I'm currently rotating and moving my sprite:

```
import SpriteKit
enum rotationDirection{
case clockwise
case counterClockwise
case none
}

   // Creates GameScene and initialises Sprites in Scene //
  class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

   // Rotation direction variable for ship motion (rotation and movement) //
var currentRotationDirection = rotationDirection.none
var xVelocity: CGFloat = 0

var sprite = SKSpriteNode()



 // Setup Scene here //
     override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    // Background colour //
    self.backgroundColor = SKColor.whiteColor()

    // sprite Physics + add's sprite //
    sprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: ship.size)
    sprite.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    sprite.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    self.addSprite()


  // Initialises sprite node and it's properties //
func addSprite() {

    // Sprite dimension properities //
    sprite.name = "sprite"
    sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "sprite")
    sprite.setScale(0.5)
    sprite.position = CGPointMake(frame.midX, 220)
    sprite.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.25)
    sprite.zPosition = 1;
    // sprite Physics properties //
    sprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: ship.size)
    sprite.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = UInt32(shipCategory)
    sprite.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    sprite.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = UInt32(obstacleCategory)
    sprite.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
    self.addChild(sprite)





 override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    // Defines UI Touch //
    let touch = touches.first as UITouch!
    let touchPosition = touch.locationInNode(self)

    // Sets up Inital Rotation Direction //
    let newRotationDirection : rotationDirection = touchPosition.x < CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) ? .clockwise : .counterClockwise


    // Left or Right movement based on touch //
    if touchPosition.x < CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) {xVelocity = -75}
    else {xVelocity = 75}


    // Clockwise or anticlockwise rotation based on touch //
    if currentRotationDirection != newRotationDirection && currentRotationDirection != .none {
        reverseRotation()
        currentRotationDirection = newRotationDirection
    }
    else if (currentRotationDirection == .none) {
        setupRotationWith(direction: newRotationDirection)
        currentRotationDirection = newRotationDirection
    }
}

func reverseRotation() {
    let oldRotateAction = sprite.actionForKey("rotate")
    let newRotateAction = SKAction.reversedAction(oldRotateAction!)
    sprite.runAction(newRotateAction(), withKey: "rotate")
}


func stopRotation() {
    sprite.removeActionForKey("rotate")
}

 func setupRotationWith(direction direction: rotationDirection){
    let angle : CGFloat = (direction == .clockwise) ? CGFloat(M_PI) : -CGFloat(M_PI)
    let rotate = SKAction.rotateByAngle(angle, duration: 2)
    let repeatAction = SKAction.repeatActionForever(rotate)
    sprite.runAction(repeatAction, withKey: "rotate")
}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    let rate: CGFloat = 0.3; //Controls rate of motion. 1.0 instantaneous, 0.0 none.
    let relativeVelocity: CGVector = CGVector(dx:xVelocity-sprite.physicsBody!.velocity.dx, dy:0);
        sprite.physicsBody!.velocity=CGVector(dx:sprite.physicsBody!.velocity.dx+relativeVelocity.dx*rate, dy:0);
    }
```

Comment: Please share some code, so we can see what you have tried.

Comment: Please find code now attached above.

Comment: Added an answer, I think you want to use acceleration. I've applied that to give a smooth movement to a circle in an earlier project. try it out on http://oceanscurse.deviantart.com/art/AS3-Shooter-Powerups-209580571

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what your are going to want to look into is acceleration. Right now you are adjusting verlocityX with a static amount using:

```
if touchPosition.x < CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) {
    xVelocity = -75
}
else {
    xVelocity = 75
}
```

Doing this will result in your jerky motion. Which is actually just linear. Using acceleration you can avoid this.

For this you'll need two more variables for `maxVelocity` and `acceleration`. You want a maxVelocity probably to limit the velocity. Each frame you'll need to increase the `velocity` with the acceleration amount.

I suggest you try something like this:

```
velocity     = 0  // No movement
acceleration = 2  // Increase velocity with 2 each frame
maxVelocity  = 75 // The maximum velocity

if touchPosition.x < CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) {
    xVelocity += acceleration
    if xVelocity <= -maxVelocity {
        xVelocity = -maxVelocity 
    }
}
else {
    xVelocity -= acceleration
    if xVelocity >= maxSpeed {
        xVelocity = maxSpeed
    }
}
```

Increasing your velocity like this will result with a rotation speed of 2 in the first frame, than 4 in the second and 6 in the thirds etc. So it will have an increasing effect. While at the same time, when trying to reverse it you wont have a jerky effect either. Say the velocity is at 50, you first decrease it to 48, 46, 44, etc. Not until the 0 point you will actually start rotating the other way.

Comment: The xVelocity refers to the lateral movement of the sprite. I want to use a similar implementation what moves the sprite laterally to the sprites angular rotation. Is this possible?